# Excel Offset formula in a cell by itself

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This phrase is embedded in many formulas on my sheet:

```
OFFSET(Table1[ReportDate],0,$B$1)
```

It returns a reference to a column in Table1.

To make those many formulas shorter, I'd like to extract this OFFSET formula to a separate cell for the others to refer to.

The OFFSET returns a reference. Putting `OFFSET(…)` in a cell just returns #VALUE, and so does `INDIRECT(OFFSET(…))`.

EDIT: The "many formulas" are SUMIFS, and the OFFSET chooses the column to be summed:

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(Table1[ReportDate],0,$B$1),Table1[ColumnB],$H10,Table1[Report Date],"<="&rYesterday)
```

Comment: can you show how it is being used in other formula.  It should return an array of values.

Comment: It is returning a column in the table, an array of values.  This cannot be contained in a single cell.  But you can replace them with the following non-volatile INDEX: `INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH("ReportDate",Table1[#Headers],0)+$B$1))`

Comment: to remove it you would need to put the address of the reference, but then you would end up using INDIRECT.  Both Address and Indirect are volatile and if used too many time will slow the calcs down as they would need to be recalced every time Excel recalcs.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the original `OFFSET` formula with something simpler to be used in other formulas.

You can do so by giving a **name** to this `OFFSET` formula.

[image: Solution]

In the above mock-up example, I have given a name `SUM_Rng` for the `OFFSET` formula and used it in my second formula, which is the same as your original SUMIFS formula.

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to bring out the **Name Manager** in Excel and add or modify **names** which can represent a reference of a cell or a range either hard-coded or returned by a formula. I noticed that you already used a name `rYesterday` in your SUMIFS formula so there should be no problem for you to add this formula to the name manager.

Cheers :)

Comment: This is useful, but I didn't want to replace OFFSET with something "simpler". My goal was to only have it appear once, and not have to calculate for every formula. But +1 because I should use this trick.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson can you please elaborate on your goal of `only have it appear once, and not have to calculate for every formula`? From what I understand it returns a range of data which is currently used in a SUMIFS formula. How can you remove this range from the SUMIFS formula to complete the calculation?

Comment: I hoped I could somehow put the OFFSET formula in $A$5, then instead of `=SUMIFS(OFFSET(Table1[ReportDate],0,$B$1)....` I could have something like `=SUMIFS($A$5....` or `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT($A$5)....`. The OFFSET would only have to calculate once instead of everywhere I used the longer formula.